# How to access mysql database of server from client machine without showing username and password?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have scenario in which my client machine can connect with my sever database. Server has mysql database. But problem is that putting connection file to my client machine. Php file from client can access my server.
I am giving all privilege to my user to access client machine. So he can able to see php file and in that php file database is connection file is include. So he/she can able to see my server ip,username and password of database. So I want to protect user to see this database detail. How it is possible? I want to give insert and update privilege to my client.

Comment: If you have phpMyAdmin it's under Users -> User Privilages. If you have a command line, find the right command with a google search.

Comment: Please don't use sql server tag for mySql questions.

Comment: If I am giving insert and update privilege then any user can alter my database. And I want to give only insert and update operation from client machine. Any other idea?

Comment: So if your problem come from a MySQL connection string located in a file that the user can access, you should create a folder, in which your connection string is stored, call this file from your original one to connect the database, and remove right for the folder that contains the .php file with the criticals information